# Recognised pattern for async loading of ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the recommend way or pattern of working with ember-data in terms of knowing when the data is loaded.  I tend to use an observer like this:

```
  groupLoaded: function(){
    if(!this.getPath('group.meta.feed')){
      return;
    }


    //do stuff with loaded entity
  }.observes('App.Controller.group.meta.feed')
```

Or I observe isLoaded.

This feels wrong, is there a better way?

Comment: How do you 'observe' isLoaded?

Comment: observes('resource.isLoaded')

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be better to use the promises that ember's router now yields WRT models from Ember Data.

Quite aware this is an old question - just clearing out the old questions.